# Is it possible for an amateur to transmit ATSC?

Tags: digital-modes, modes, atv

Amateur television has long used the NTSC (analog) television standards to transmit video and audio. Several years ago, the digital broadcast television transition made higher-quality television signals possible. Can amateurs acquire and use digital television (ATSC or DVB) transmission equipment?

Comment: Here's an example of it being used in practice: http://www.tvtechnology.com/broadcast-engineering/0029/ham-tv-operators-go-high-definition/277772

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FCC Regulations, Title 97.307(f)(8) says yes, you can transmit with ATSC modulation in the US, BUT you can't use frequencies which match US ATSC channels. You would need to find a receiver (maybe PC controlled?) flexible enough to  listen to amateur frequencies.

As to DVB-T or DVD-S, well, they'll work with about 2MHz of bandwidth instead of the 6MHz slice required for ATSC. Again, a flexible receiver is called for.

Comment: You have to use 6 MHz to do ATSC? What if you only want to transmit one video stream with <32 Mbit/s?

Comment: Good answer, assuming the US.  (ATSC is used in several other countries, where FCC regulations will not apply.)

Answer (score 2):

Software defined radios (SDRs) that can transmit can certainly do this. In the [GNUradio](http://gnuradio.org/) software, for example, there are blocks for receiving and transmitting ATSC; cf. [this blog post for how to receive and decode ATSC with a SDR](https://coolsdrstuff.blogspot.com/2015/09/watching-atsc-hdtv-on-sdrplay-rsp.html?m=1).